# Should we have an Arduino tag?

Tags: discussion, arduino

Arduino has its own stack now... Aside from the meta, Should we get rid of the tag? If not, what Arduino related questions belong in EE.SE that don't belong in AR.SE?

It's hard to think of many examples that don't also have a place in Computer Science, or Data Science.

Comment: related meta thread: [Poor abused Arduino tag](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/poor-abused-arduino-tag)

Comment: I read that one, but nobody really decided what was for EE, and what was for AR.

Comment: Can I just say one more time that writing it as "AR.SE" makes me giggle. This is important to consider.

Answer (score 5):

Overlap between sites is fine. A strict "This question belongs on site Y instead of site X" interpretation is not a productive mandate. Olin, for all his Arduino bashing, has answered more questions tagged [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) than [op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/op-amp), and [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) remains the most-used tag on our site.

The tag is staying, and it remains useful on the majority of questions it is on (i.e. it isn't a "meta" tag)

Comment: ***slow clap***

Comment: so, then is crossposting completely fine?

Comment: @tuskiomi Cross-posting is never fine

Answer (score 2):

The tag is doing better than I thought.  By my count, out of the 50 newest questions with this tag, 16 have been closed, and 8 have been migrated.

That said, of the ones remaining, I still feel a good deal of them have been inappropriately tagged.  There are a small handful where Arduino is the ONLY tag, and we should certainly find a way to stop that.  It will be hard to convince me that in that case, the tag has any meaning at all.

The rest look sort of on the OK side, though.  My biggest concern would be that the askers don't learn how to find their own answers if they only know to convey their question as "Arduino", but that doesn't look like its a huge problem.

Comment: Interesting to know! I will probably check this out further myself. Thanks!

Comment: Tag [tag:arduino] is still used as a meta-tag, and not infrequently.  Case in point: [Difference between shunt resistant measurement circuits using op amps](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260237/difference-between-shunt-resistant-measurement-circuits-using-op-amps) .  Arduino isn't mentioned neither in the body, nor in the title.  I usually remove the [tag:arduino] tag in such cases.

Comment: There could be real reasons why [tag:arduino] tag has got better mental health now, compared to what it was a couple of years ago. (1) We've got a separate Arduino.SE, and it's fortified with a seasoned Arduino community moderator Nick Gammon.  (2) Arduino community at large is growing more reasonable over the years (so does one hope, at least).